# Overlapping cut function r

Tags: r, overlap, cut, shingles

I have a dataset of GPS locations that looks like this.

```
library(tidyverse)
seg.length.m <-2500
d <- tibble(
UTC = c('2021-12-02 15:34:00','2021-12-02 15:35:00','2021-12-02 15:36:00','2021-12-02 15:37:00','2021-12-02 15:38:00','2021-12-02 15:39:00','2021-12-02 15:40:00','2021-12-02 15:41:00','2021-12-02 15:42:00','2021-12-02 15:43:00'),
Lat = c('-57.5328713333333','-57.5355708333333','-57.5379695','-57.54041','-57.5429036666667','-57.5452343333333','-57.547898','-57.550008','-57.5523958333333','-57.5547928333333'),
Lon = c('-52.8311235','-52.8234366666667','-52.8165898333333','-52.8099165','-52.8025293333333','-52.7961175','-52.7887356666667','-52.7823455','-52.7759113333333','-52.7689473333333'),
transect = c('1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'), 
distance = c('559.716068583762','498.202858146185','491.293157455882','532.341915485295','471.188754640846','541.338131747554','457.918685684549','475.555477163174','504.209591568878','474.017635562939'))
```

Where **transect** is my transect number, there is a few hundred of them and **distance** is the distance (meters) from one location to the next. I want break these transects into smaller segments of **seg.length.m** which in this case is 2500 meters.

There are a few other **group_by** variables, but this is the code i have.

```
segmented <- d |>
  group_by(transect) |> 
  mutate(sd_c = cumsum(distance),
         cum_int =  cut(sd_c,
                        breaks = seq(from = 0,
                                     # to is the greater or seg.length.m, max sd_c
                                     to = ifelse(ceiling(max(sd_c, na.rm=T)) < seg.length.m,
                                            seg.length.m,
                                            ceiling(max(sd_c, na.rm=T))),
                                     #by 
                                     by = seg.length.m), right =T, include.lowest=T, labels=F
         )
  ) |> 
  ungroup() |>
  arrange(UTC)
```

current output

```
segmented
```

desired output

```
segmented |> rbind( segmented[4,] |> mutate(cum_int =2)) |> rbind( segmented[9,] |> mutate(cum_int = NA)) |> arrange(UTC)
```

to then feed through

```
segmented <- segmented |>
      group_by(transect, cum_int) |> 
      summarise(seg_length = sum(as.numeric(distance)))|> 
      mutate(cum_int = ifelse(is.na(cum_int), lag(cum_int)+1, cum_int))
```

The issue i have is that it i want **cut** to have an overlap, so the last row in the first segment is the repeated in the first row of the second segment. **cut** might not be the best function here, but can't find a better way, **shingle**?

This data is actually an sf spatial dataframe, which means the points (held in geometry) are concatenated when i **summaries()** ,  and then i **st_cast** them as "LINESTRINGS".

Currently these linestrings have gaps between them, which i want to removed.

Thanks internet, i hope my question is clear. :)

Comment: I don't really understand your question.  Is it possible to make it more minimal?  Do you really need all of the timestamps and lat and long to explain your question?  Could you rephrase it with only a single dimension of intervals and id numbers?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Michael Dewar, i hope this is clearer, i am not quite sure where a fix would go in this code, hence leaving some complexity in there.

Comment: Just made an additional slight change @MichaelDewar thanks :)

Comment: Actually it seems less clear because you added stuff.  I was suggesting you take stuff away.  Perhaps I'm just not the right person to answer this.  But you should try really hard to ask a single, minimal question.  Potential answerers are hesitant to wade through many lines of code with lots of irrelevant details.  (I mean irrelevant to solving your current problem.  I know that they mean a lot to you.  But they aren't relevant for solving your problem.). It looks like you are only computing on distance.  Delete lat and long and UTC from your entire question.  Rename transect as group_id.

Comment: Replace your example with distances that are integers.  If you *really* need time dimension, at least use an integer and call it time, not UTC.  If your question looks like only GIS superstars can answer it, then you will struggle to unlock the power of the community.